# Scale instance on points?

Tags: geometry-nodes, transforms

I have geo node with curve to points and then instance on points. I have managed to get my objects rotated along the curve. I would like to scale the instances to have them smaller at the ends of the curve, but I can't figure out how to do that.

I have tried messing around with the float curve node that I saw in similar questions asked, but I couldn't get it to work. What am I doing wrong/missing?

Here is a link to my blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15TcJV1zJZveuASgnzk5_MP_B2QUUBpfU/view?usp=sharing
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be this setting:

[image]

Get the index and map it from 0 to the domain size targeting 0 to 1.

Then input it in the float curve you already made and plug the result to the scale of the instance.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. Thank you so much! It would have taken me ages to figure that out on my own.